# How to implement shift+click in angular2-tree-component

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement angular2-tree-component in my application, And i want to add option to select the range of node using shift+click like in file system.

Please guide me how to implement this.
agular2-tree link https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs

Answer (score 0):

it's just the setting for shift event.
I hope this helps.

```
const actionMapping:IActionMapping = {
  mouse: {
    click: (tree, node, $event) => {
      $event.shiftKey
        ? TREE_ACTIONS.TOGGLE_SELECTED_MULTI(tree, node, $event)
        : TREE_ACTIONS.TOGGLE_SELECTED(tree, node, $event)
    }
  }
};

@Component({
  selector: 'tree-test',
  templateUrl: 'tree-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['tree-test.component.css']
})

export class TreeTestComponent {
  options = {
    actionMapping
  };

  // get data for nodes
}
```